# Android EditText invalid unicode for Postgres

Tags: android, postgresql, unicode

In my app, a string was typed in a EditText and sent to a api, but a error ocurred when the api stored the string in a postgres db.

The string was sent inside a json:

```
{"description":"Fix finish of \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 power plug. Good start. Loose Current "}
```

The string was captured from the EditText:

```
descriptionField.getText().toString();
```

The error in postgres is:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  unsupported Unicode escape sequence
```

I can't reproduce the insertion of `\u0000` in the EditText.

Any suggestion to how to block to this `\u0000` to be uploaded to the api?

Comment: The json was build using `com.google.code.gson`